# Is it possible to let the mouse control hand animation?

Tags: animation, skeletal-animation

I want to let the player control hand motion with the mouse is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible.

What are you using?

I don't have much experience in 3D at all, but I imagine it would be as simple (at least to start) as attaching the mouse input to the center of the hand, imposing limits, smoothing input, etc.

With something like Unity I imagine you could do it in a matter of minutes, albeit a rough implementation.

As long as the hand has at least one joint in it, I can't imagine it would be very difficulty to at least begin prototyping.

Wouldn't it be identical to using the WASD keys for movement? Just instead of a central point on the entire entity, it would just be a central point on the hand joint, or an object you created within the hand which moves the mesh around with the hand as a lead.

The same as dynamically animating a skeleton in any way outside of precanned animations.

Comment: I'm using blender just to let you know.